# SNR of a pulsed signal in noise

Tags: signal-analysis

I have a digitized acoustic data of length L in which a pulsed signal (chirp) of finite duration and bandwidth is merged starting at some time instant t1 and ending at time instant t2. I wan to calculate SNR of this pulse signal. What is the best way to calculate this SNR?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: well, you detect the chirp, and subtract it from the mixture. The remainder is your signal of interest (plus other sources of noise which you don't mention). Then you calculate the power of each component, and calculate the ratio. That's SNR.

Comment: @Marcus this is a fine answer, why not include it as such below?

Answer (score 1):

You detect the chirp, and subtract it from the mixture. The remainder is your signal of interest (plus other sources of noise which you don't mention). Then you calculate the power of each component, and calculate the ratio. That's SNR.

The challenge is usually detecting the chirp, but that can be done, depending on the level of information you have about it (chirp rate, phase of the chirp, beginning of the chirp, bandwidth, amplitude) using simple techniques like a correlation with a prototype chirp, or "blinder" methods like letting a PLL run on the signal and watching when it locks.